# Realizar um Get que recebe como parâmetros um List<long> ids

Tags: c#, entity-framework

tudo bem?

Estou realizando um projeto em C# e no momento estou fazendo os métodos para ser consumido por via API Rest, meu chefe pediu para fazer um HttpGet que recebe como parâmetro um List ids.

Sei que na minha Controller o método tem essa estrutura

```
[HttpGet("{ids}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> BuscaPorListaIds(IList<long> ids)
        {
            return Response(_mapper.Map<IList<MinhaViewModel>>(_repository.GetListIds));
        }
```

A minha duvida é como posso fazer o método no meu Repository, não sei como posso implementar o método para fazer essa consulta no banco, com vários ids, sei que no sql é dessa maneira `select * from MinhaTabela where id in (1,2,4,5)`

Por enquanto meu repository está assim:

```
public ICollection<MinhaModel> GetListIds(IList<long> ids)
        {
            // Exemplo incompleto, pois não sei como posso fazer esse return para a pesquisa no banco, sei que no final preciso adicionar o .ToList()
            return Db.MinhaModel.AsNoTracking()
        }
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Se tiver alguma coisa errada no meu código, podem me falar tbm, pfvr;

Comment: Esse Db.MinhaModel é uma lista ou um objeto apenas?

Comment: Sei que ao final tenho que colocar .ToList() para transformar o objeto em lista

Comment: Mas esse Db.MinhaModel, quando você para o mouse em cima dele, qual o tipo desse valor? É uma coleção? List, Array, IEnumerable, ICollection, IQueryable, IList? Alguma coisa do tipo?

Comment: É uma model, um objeto apenas, não é uma coleção

Comment: Você não sabe como passar e receber os parâmetros na query string? Ou não sabe como fazer o filtro na consulta pro banco de dados.

Comment: Não sei como fazer o filtro na consulta para o banco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu Repository faça o return da seguinte maneira:

```
public ICollection<MinhaModel> GetListIds(IList<long> ids)
        {
            return Db.MinhaModel.AsNoTracking().Where(p => ids.Any(x => x == p.Id)).ToList();
        }
```

Vc terá que fazer um ajuste na sua Controller, pois vc não esta passando o parâmetro no método do seu repository e também se vc deixar dessa maneira, na hora que você dar o GET, dará um erro, pois desse modo o c# entende que vc esta passando um corpo no seu método, o GET não se deve passar nenhum tipo de corpo. Então o correto será assim:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> BuscarPorListaIds([FromQuery] IList<long> id)
{
     return Response(_mapper.Map<IList<MinhaViewModel>>(_repository.GetListIds(id)));
}
```

Comment: Eu gostaria de fazer uma pequena alteração na parte do endpoint GET.
Seria bem melhor altera-lo para um [HttpPost], e passar a lista de id via [FromBody], pois dependendo da quantidade de Id que você passar, desse modo [FromQuery] irá quebrar. O restante do código esta certo, só gostaria de criar um alerta para essa alteração